# In Opera how to open a link from a private tab in a normal tab?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tabs, opera

There are search engines I don't trust, which is why I keep searches inside private tabs. Is it possible (and how) to open a normal tab from a private tab? I.e. so that if one of the search results points to a website (like this one here) where I can vote and where I'm logged in, I can vote?!

Currently I do:

- <kbd>F8</kbd> (go to URL bar)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (snip the URL)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (open new normal tab)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste URL)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> (load the URL)

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the "inner" three steps means I can keep the finger on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> of course, but it would still be good to have an easier shortcut than the above ... uhm procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>F8</kbd> (Go to URL bar)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Open the selected link in a new tab)

Some more nifty short-cuts on the [Opera Help Page.](http://help.opera.com/Linux/9.50/en/keyboard.html)

Comment: how does that help me, except that it opens the *search* in a new tab? I want a link on the page with the search results opened in a normal tab, not the *search itself*.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. You said you wanted an easier shortcut to the one you currently use. The solution I have posted does shorten the process you're currently using to snip and paste a URL.

Comment: you are right. My question was wrongly worded. Your answer perfectly answers the question as asked.

Comment: No problems, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Opera 12.xx is customizable in many ways. In newer Opera 15 versions it's not so easy anymore to modify things. Anyway, in Opera 12, you can:

Set up two custom shortcuts under `Preferences » Advanced » Shortcuts » Keyboard setup » edit`. Use `&` to execute multiple commands

```
Copy document address & New page & Paste and go
Copy document address & New private page & Paste and go
```

[image]

***(or)***

---

Add custom mouse gestures. Its basically the same procedure as for shortcuts.
Go to `Preferences » Advanced » Shortcuts » Mouse setup » edit` and add your shortcuts

[image]

***(or)***

---

[Edit your context menu](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/edit-menu-setup)

[image]

1. Create a new context menu by duplicating your current one under `Preferences » Advanced » Toolbars » Menu setup`. Select *Opera standard* and hit *duplicate*
2. Close Opera
3. Search your profile folder depending on what Opera mode you use

   - installed mode » `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Opera\profile\menu\`
   - portable mode » `..\Opera\profile\menu\`
4. In a sub-folder called *menu* you will notice a file called `standard_menu (1).ini`. Open it with any editor and look at   the section [Document Popup Menu]. Insert new context menu entries by adding these lines

   ```
   Item, Open in private tab = Copy document address,,,,"New private page menu" & New private page & Paste & go
   Item, Open in normal tab  = Copy document address,,,,"New page menu" & New page & Paste & go
   ```
5. Save & Close the file and re-open Opera. Make sure the new layout is still selected/enabled under `Preferences » Advanced » Toolbars » Menu setup`